# What does "More Money" stack with?

Tags: bravely-default

The description of "More Money" (the Merchant Class Specialty) is

"Earn 1.5 times more money than normal after a battle. Note that this effect does not stack with similar effects from items, but the bonus from multiple characters using this ability does stack."

I am not seeing an increase in pg earned after battle even though all four of my characters have it on. What does it actually stack with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More Money does **NOT** stack with itself. Multiple characters having the More Money ability will not increase your pg earned. The description was a mistranslation. More Money **DOES** stack with items like [Golden Egg](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Golden_Egg#Golden_Egg).

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/729328-bravely-default/68317819

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/729328-bravely-default/68287566

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/729328-bravely-default/68100397

Comment: Wait, so it is the other way around from what the description of the skill says?

Comment: Yes. It is the opposite.

Comment: I can confirm that 2 "More Money"s garners the same PG from the same enemies as does 1 "More Money".