# How do the Bonus Reward skills/items interact with each other? (JP Up, Exp Up, More Money, Growth Egg and Golden Egg)

Tags: bravely-default

There are three skills and two items that boost experience, jp, and pg rewards at the end of battle. The items are the Growth Egg and Golden Egg. The skills are JP up, Experience Up, and More Money. How do they all interact with each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Growth Egg: It removes the pg reward but doubles exp and jp.

The Golden Egg: It removes exp and jp rewards but doubles the amount of pg received.

JP Up is: Earn 1.2x more job points.

Experience Up: Earn 1.5x more exp.

More Money: Earn 1.5x more pg.

The Growth Egg and Golden Egg accessories and More Money skill are PARTY bonuses. You only need to have 1 equipped and the entire party benefits. These bonuses are displayed to the player at the end of battle. NONE of these stack with themselves. Two Golden Eggs will still only grant a 2x bonus and two "More Money" skills will only grant a 1.5x bonus.

If a monster grants 100 pg and you have the Golden Egg equipped the PG reward will say 200 (100 * 2 (for the Egg)) pg. If ANYBODY has the Golden Egg equipped and ANYBODY has More Money equipped, the reward will say 300(100 * 2 (for the Egg) * 1.5 (For More Money)).

This is also explained about the same in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/156190/what-does-more-money-stack-with).

Equipping BOTH the Growth Egg and Golden Egg will net you NO REWARDS no matter what other skills you have equipped.

JP Up and Experience Up are INDIVIDUAL bonuses. ONLY the party member that has it equipped will receive the bonus. These bonuses are otherwise NOT displayed to the player.

If a monster grants 10 JP and Tiz has JP Up equipped, the reward screen will still say 10 JP BUT Tiz will receive 12 and everybody else in the party will only receive 10 JP.

These DO stack with the Growth Egg though. If a monster grants 10 JP, Tiz has JP Up equipped and ANYBODY has the Growth Egg equipped, the reward screen will show 20 JP and Tiz will receive 24 JP.

ALL of these items/skills do their calculations AFTER battle bonuses like 1-Turn Victor, Unscathed, and Sweeper. So if are a '1-turn Victor Hero', a monster grants 10 EXP, Tiz has Experience Up and ANYBODY has a Growth Egg, you will see an experience reward of 30 ((10 + 5 (for the 1-turn victor)) * 2 (for the growth egg)). Tiz will earn 45 exp and everybody else will earn 30.